# Hiding dynamic div tag, containing dynamic input buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I create a div tag dynamically inside of a  tag in C#(Asp.net) that will contain 3 dynamically generated buttons. I only want the div to display when the user mouses over the table cell(td tag). Can I acheive this throug .css?

The dynamic generation in C# looks like this:

```
HtmlTableCell cell = (HtmlTableCell)c;

                        HtmlInputButton PopupAddButton = new HtmlInputButton();
                        PopupAddButton.ID = "PBA" + c.ID.ToString();
                        PopupAddButton.Value = "Add";
                        PopupAddButton.Style["Height"] = "14px";
                        PopupAddButton.Style["Width"] = "40px";
                        PopupAddButton.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, "-100");
                        PopupAddButton.Style["right"] = "0";
                        PopupAddButton.Style["float"] = "left";
                        PopupAddButton.Style["vertical-align"] = "top";
                        PopupAddButton.Style["font-size"] = "9px";

                        HtmlInputButton PopupEditButton = new HtmlInputButton();
                        PopupEditButton.ID = "PBE" + c.ID.ToString();
                        PopupEditButton.Value = "Edit";
                        PopupEditButton.Style["Height"] = "14px";
                        PopupEditButton.Style["Width"] = "40px";
                        PopupEditButton.Style["top"] = "0";
                        PopupEditButton.Style["right"] = "0";
                        PopupEditButton.Style["float"] = "left";
                        PopupEditButton.Style["vertical-align"] = "top";
                        PopupEditButton.Style["font-size"] = "9px";

                        HtmlInputButton PopupDeleteButton = new HtmlInputButton();
                        PopupDeleteButton.ID = "PBD" + c.ID.ToString();
                        PopupDeleteButton.Value = "Delete";
                        PopupDeleteButton.Style["Height"] = "14px";
                        PopupDeleteButton.Style["Width"] = "40px";
                        PopupDeleteButton.Style["top"] = "0";
                        PopupDeleteButton.Style["right"] = "0";
                        PopupDeleteButton.Style["float"] = "left";
                        PopupDeleteButton.Style["font-size"] = "9px";
                        PopupDeleteButton.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.VerticalAlign, "top");


                        PopupAddButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "AddPopupControlToTableCell('" + cell.ClientID + "', '" + cell.Height.ToString() + "', '" + g_PopupControlId + "');");
                        PopupEditButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "EditPopupControlToTableCell('" + cell.ClientID + "', '" + cell.Height.ToString() + "', '" + g_PopupControlId + "');");
                        PopupDeleteButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "DeletePopupControlToTableCell('" + cell.ClientID + "', '" + cell.Height.ToString() + "', '" + g_PopupControlId + "');");

                        HtmlGenericControl ButtonDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        ButtonDiv.ID = "buttonBlock" + c.ID.ToString();
                        ButtonDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "buttonBlock");

                        ButtonDiv.Controls.Add(PopupAddButton);
                        ButtonDiv.Controls.Add(PopupEditButton);
                        ButtonDiv.Controls.Add(PopupDeleteButton);

                        cell.Controls.Add(ButtonDiv);
```

my .css currently looks like this

```
.buttonBlock input{
  display:none;
}
td:hover #buttonBlock input{
 display:inline;
}
```

This does not work however. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: in what way is it not working? is the hover just not working? are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try fixing this code first

```
td:hover #buttonBlock input{
display:inline;
}
```

to

```
td:hover .buttonBlock input{
display:inline;}
```

your original was looking for an id of buttonBlock (`#buttonBlock`) when it should be looking for a class of buttonBlock (`.buttonBlock`)

Comment: Thanks peroija! Im still very green with .css but this did the trick!